# Connecting HTML web page with mssql database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to connect my html form to a database hosted through godaddy.com. I have the database with tables setup through SQL Server Management Studio and I have my html form made in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. The SQL is connected to my godaddy account. What I cannot figure out is how to connect my form to the SQL. Is it something I can do with js or php or C#? I just need a basic example of how to connect it and I think I can figure it out.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function trim(tbx) { tbx.value = (tbx.value).trim(); }
        function done(){
            frm = document.LoginForm;

            var checkString = function(testChar, alpha, num, specialChars){
                if(alpha!==true)alpha=false;
                if(num!==true)num=false;
                if(specialChars==null)specialChars="";

                for(tc = 0; tc < testChar.length;tc++){
                    var r = true;
                    if(!alpha && testChar[tc].match(/^[a-z]+$/i)) return false;
                    if(!num && testChar[tc].match(/^[0-9]+$/i)) return false;

                    if(!testChar[tc].match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) && !checkSpecialChars(testChar[tc])) return false;
                }
                return true;

                function checkSpecialChars(c){
                    for(sc = 0; sc < specialChars.length;sc++){
                        if(specialChars[sc]==c){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }               
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function test_name(name){
                var t = name;
                if (t.length<2 || t.length>35){
                    alert("Names must be between 2 and 35 letters.");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if (!checkString(name,true,false,"'- ")){
                        alert("Names are made up of letters and sometime apostasies, dashes and spaces.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            function test_un(){
                var t = frm.un.value;

                if (t.length<5 || t.length>14){
                    alert("Usernames must be between 5 and 14 letters.");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
                    if (i==0){
                        if (!t[i].match(/^[a-z]+$/i)){
                            alert("Usernames must start with a letter.")
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!checkString(t[i],true,true,"_")){
                        alert("Usernames must be made up of letters, numbers and underscores.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            function test_pw(){
                var t = frm.pw.value;

                if (t.length<7 || t.length>14){
                    alert("Passwords must be between 7 and 14 letters.");
                    return false;
                }
                if (t!==frm.pc.value) {
                    alert("Your password and password confirmation do not match.")
                    return false;
                }
                for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
                    if (!checkString(t[i],true,true,">@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=")){
                        alert("Passwords must be made up of: \n  - at least one letter \n  - numbers \n  - any of the following: \n           <>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=");
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            if (!test_name(frm.fn.value)){
                frm.fn.focus();
                frm.fn.select();
            }
            else if (!test_name(frm.ln.value)){
                frm.ln.focus();
                frm.ln.select();
            }
            else if (!test_un()){
                frm.un.focus();
                frm.un.select();
            }
            else if (!test_pw()){
                frm.pw.focus();
                frm.pw.select();
            }
            else{
                alert(
                "Name: " + frm.fn.value + " " + frm.ln.value + "\n" +
                "Username: " + frm.un.value + "\n" +
                "Password: " + frm.pw.value);
                frm.fn.value = "";
                frm.ln.value = "";
                frm.un.value = "";
                frm.pw.value = "";
                frm.pc.value = "";
                frm.fn.focus();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="LoginForm"><table style="width:300px">
        <table>
            <tr><td>First Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="fn" onblur="trim(document.LoginForm.fn);" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="ln" onblur="trim(document.LoginForm.ln);" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Username: </td> <td><input type="text" name="un" onblur="trim(document.LoginForm.un);" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password: </td> <td><input type="password" name="pw" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Confirm: </td> <td><input type="password" name="pc" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="Button" value="Submit!" onClick="done()" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <form name="UserList">
        <table border="1px">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some server side technology for connecting it to database(Javascript can also be used as a serverside technology eg:Node.js)
since u are familiar with C# , i think u can use asp

Check this link, Will be helpful for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371(v=vs.100).ASPX

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) that will be hosted on `GoDaddy` as well (you mentioned C# in your question. It is very easy to implement it in C#...).

The webservice will know how to:

1. Get requests from clients (such as your HTML site).
2. Query the database.

You HTML site can communicate with the web service using javascript.

You can take a look [here](http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-web-service-in-cnet.html#.UyqaZfmSxIE) about implementing a web service in C#.